# SharePoint 2013 REST API Filtering With Count

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How can we count list items by filtering? For example there is a task list and I want to count specified user's task count

I tried

http://www.siteurl.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Tasks')/itemcount?$filter=AssignedTo/ID eq 2

but it returns me all items count. Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No, unfortunately. Solved with JSOM.. Because there is no method to do that

Comment: Actually it can be done. Check this link https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/215802/58747

Comment: @VishnuS Is there a way to get the count straight away, without getting the results first? Retrieving all results defeats the purpose when count is used for something like paging with lazy loading.

Comment: @CanPERK Can you elaborate on how you solved this with JSOM please? I'm facing this very same issue.

Comment: Sorry man, It was ages ago and I have no idea what I did... Maybe I made it a client side filtering and ordering most probably

Comment: @ΕГИІИО you can use `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/ItemCount`. Check this link: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/139389/58747